# How many characters need to be escaped?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP.

I use two ways to escaping string:

## method 1. by using replace

```
function htmlreplace($str, $useBR = false) {
    $str2 = $str;
    $str2 = preg_replace ( "/</", "&lt;", $str2 );
    $str2 = preg_replace ( "/>/", "&gt;", $str2 );
    $str2 = preg_replace ( "/(\r\n|\n|\r)/", $useBR ? "<br />" : " ", $str2 );
    $str2 = preg_replace ( "/&/", "&amp;", $str2 );
    $str2 = preg_replace ( "/\'/", "&#39;", $str2 );
    return preg_replace ( "/\"/", "&#34;", $str2 );
}
$string='some string needs to insert into mysql';
stripslashes(htmlreplace($string));
```

## method 2. After connecting to MySQL

```
function sanitizeString($var, $DBconnection) {
    $var = strip_tags ( $var );
    $var = htmlentities ( $var );
    $var = stripslashes ( $var );
    return $DBconnection->real_escape_string ( $var );
}
$string='some string needs to insert into mysql';
trim ( sanitizeString ($string) );
```

From 
[SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_Wildcard_characters_in_Like_Clauses)

shows these characters need to escape

NUL,
 BS,
 TAB,
 LF,
 CR,
 SUB,
 %,
 ',
 \,
 _,
 all other non-alphanumeric characters with ASCII values less than 256

From [PHP addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

shows addslashes() function will escape these characters: single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte)

As far as I know, escaping is for prevent SQL injection.

So I am curious about how many characters need to be escaped? what are they? Are they all [Special Characters in HTML](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php)?

As for SQL injection prevent, thanks to Slico, Marc B, and bub help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just use PDO with prepared statements? There is a [nice post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) on SO regarding SQL injections

Comment: No. You don't "blacklist" characters. If anything ever changes, your list will be obsolete and allow problems. This is exactly the **WRONG** way of preventing sql injection. You don't allow it to happen in the first place by using the tools properly: prepared statements with placeholders. Then you don't have to worry AT ALL about what chars MIGHT be malicious, and let the DB itself do all the worrying for you.

Comment: HTML really doesn't have much to do with SQL injection anyway.

Comment: SQL Injection is *always* a big issue @Chay22

Comment: thank you @bub ,I will using it.

Comment: @MarcB  thanks for explain prepared statements to me:)

Comment: @JayBlanchard you are right! SQL Injection is always a big issue!

Comment: @Chay22 really dangerous way of thinking...

Answer (score 1):

From OWASP take a look at this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet):

Primary Defenses:

- Option #1: Use of Prepared Statements (Parameterized Queries)
- Option #2: Use of Stored Procedures
- Option #3: Escaping all User Supplied Input

Additional Defenses:

- Also Enforce: Least Privilege
- Also Perform: White List Input Validation

Comment: Does my method 2 Escape all characters?

Comment: May I do Escape before do Prepared Statements?